# Get Material UI Slider value in onDragStop event

Tags: reactjs, slider, material-ui

I want to fire an event `onDragStop` rather than `onChange` using a Material UI `Slider` in my React app (so that the event fires fewer times). However, the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider) indicates that the `onDragStop` function signature only has the mouseevent: `function(event: object) => void`. So, the following works with `onChange`:

```
<Slider onChange={ (e, val) => this.props.update(e, control.id, val) }  />
```

However, this event doesn't have a second parameter `val`:

```
<Slider onDragStop={ (e, val) => this.props.update(e, control.id, val) }  />
```

How can I get the current value of the Slider in the `onDragStop` function? Note, I'm unable to use `this`, as it refers to the parent component.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Also ran into this problem! If you use a component inside a class, use both callbacks:

```
<Slider onChange={ (e, val) => this.val = val }  
        onDragStop={ (e) => this.props.update(e, control.id, this.val)
/>
```

Answer (score 36):

In a newer version of Material UI you could use:

```
<Slider
  onChange={} // for example updating a state value
  onChangeCommitted={} // for example fetching new data
/>
```

Comment: This answer is the new best answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
<Slider
  // invoked when the user drags the thumb
  onChange={(_, newValue) => update(newValue)}
  // invoked when the user drops the thumb
  onChangeCommitted={(_, newValue) => update(newValue)}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 4):

If you want the `Slider` value to be part of the component state, e.g. for triggering a re-render of the `Slider` when it changes (this requires you to pass `this.state.value` to the `Slider` as well), you can do this:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Slider value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onDragStop={this.handleDragStop}/>
    }

    handleChange = (event, value) => this.setState({ value });

    handleDragStop = () => this.props.update(this.state.value);
}
```

Otherwise you can just assign the value to `this`:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Slider onChange={this.handleChange} onDragStop={this.handleDragStop}/>
    }

    handleChange = (event, value) => this.value = value;

    handleDragStop = () => this.props.update(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is super late, but I wanted to add my two cents:

If all you need is to not constantly fire an event, you can use debouncing like this:

```
const handleSliderChange = useCallback((event, value) => {
debounceSliderChange(value);
}, []);

const debounceSliderChange = debounce((val) => {
setValue(val)
}, 200);
```

and then:

```
<Slider onChange={(e, v) => handleSliderChange(e, v)}/>
```

For reference, I am importing debounce from: "@mui/material/utils"

### Demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dirac-fij37p?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import Slider from '@mui/material/Slider';
    
    function YourComponent() {
      // Set an initial value for maxDistance
      const [maxDistance, setMaxDistance] = useState(/* initial value */);
    
      // Handle the Slider value change when the user commits to a value
      const handleSliderChange = (event, value) => {
        setMaxDistance(value);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="non-linear-slider">Max Distance:</label>
          <Slider
            defaultValue={maxDistance}
            step={5}
            onChangeCommitted={handleSliderChange}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            aria-labelledby="non-linear-slider"
          />
          <p>Current Max Distance: {maxDistance}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default YourComponent;


//use this Example using the onChangeCommitted ,it will work
```