# How to I retrieve value from Material UI Slider to use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, material-ui, react-props

I want to retrieve the value of the slider `onDragStop` to use as a `const` and apply to different parts of my code but I'm not sure how I should go about doing this. Where do I declare my `const sliderValue` and how do I update it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get material ui slider value in onDragStop event (react)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440051/get-material-ui-slider-value-in-ondragstop-event-react)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onChangeCommitted` on `Slider` for `material-ui`. Here is the example how you can use `onChangeCommitted`

```
<Slider
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onChangeCommitted={(event, newValue) =>
          alert("You stopped your slider on " + newValue)
        }
        aria-labelledby="continuous-slider"
      />
```

**[Here is the Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-hmjtz)**

Comment: i would like to use the `newValue` value somewhere else in my code, how do I do that?

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer in the code sand box https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-hmjtz